# Unity gpu instancing shader wrong rotations

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders

I am trying to make unity render lots of (1M) cubes all with different rotation, position and color. Position and color work fine, but the rotations are somehow calculated wrong. It manifests mostly when I rotate them around the x or z axes over 180 degrees.
Here is my code:

```
Shader "Instanced/InstancedSurfaceShader" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model
    #pragma surface surf Standard addshadow fullforwardshadows
    #pragma multi_compile_instancing
    #pragma instancing_options procedural:setup

    sampler2D _MainTex;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

#ifdef UNITY_PROCEDURAL_INSTANCING_ENABLED
    StructuredBuffer<float4> positionBuffer;
    StructuredBuffer<float4> colorBuffer;
    StructuredBuffer<float4> rotationBuffer;
#endif
    void setup()
    {

#ifdef UNITY_PROCEDURAL_INSTANCING_ENABLED
    float4 position     = positionBuffer[unity_InstanceID];
    float4 q             = rotationBuffer[unity_InstanceID];
    float qr            = q[0];
    float qi            = q[1];
    float qj            = q[2];
    float qk            = q[3];

    float4x4 rotation;
    float4x4 translation = {
        1,0,0,position.x,
        0,1,0,position.y,
        0,0,1,position.z,
        0,0,0,1
    };

    // quaternion to matrix
    // http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix

    rotation[0][0]            = 1.0f - 2.0f*qj*qj - 2.0f*qk*qk;
    rotation[0][1]            = 2.0f*(qi*qj - qk*qr);
    rotation[0][2]            = 2.0f*(qi*qk + qj*qr);
    rotation[0][3]            = 0.0f;

    rotation[1][0]            = 2.0f*(qi*qj+qk*qr);
    rotation[1][1]            = 1.0f - 2.0f*qi*qi - 2.0f*qk*qk;
    rotation[1][2]            = 2.0f*(qj*qk - qi*qr);
    rotation[1][3]            = 0.0f;

    rotation[2][0]            = 2.0f*(qi*qk - qj*qr);
    rotation[2][1]            = 2.0f*(qj*qk + qi*qr);
    rotation[2][2]            = 1.0f - 2.0f*qi*qi - 2.0f*qj*qj;
    rotation[2][3]            = 0.0f;

    rotation[3][0]            = 0.0f;
    rotation[3][1]            = 0.0f;
    rotation[3][2]            = 0.0f;
    rotation[3][3]            = 1.0f;

    unity_ObjectToWorld = mul(translation, rotation);
    //unity_WorldToObject = inverse(unity_ObjectToWorld);
     
    // inverse transform matrix
    // taken from richardkettlewell's post on
    // https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/drawmeshinstancedindirect-example-comments-and-questions.446080/

    float3x3 w2oRotation;
    w2oRotation[0] = unity_ObjectToWorld[1].yzx * unity_ObjectToWorld[2].zxy - unity_ObjectToWorld[1].zxy * unity_ObjectToWorld[2].yzx;
    w2oRotation[1] = unity_ObjectToWorld[0].zxy * unity_ObjectToWorld[2].yzx - unity_ObjectToWorld[0].yzx * unity_ObjectToWorld[2].zxy;
    w2oRotation[2] = unity_ObjectToWorld[0].yzx * unity_ObjectToWorld[1].zxy - unity_ObjectToWorld[0].zxy * unity_ObjectToWorld[1].yzx;

    float det = dot(unity_ObjectToWorld[0], w2oRotation[0]);

    w2oRotation = transpose(w2oRotation);

    w2oRotation *= rcp(det);

    float3 w2oPosition = mul(w2oRotation, -unity_ObjectToWorld._14_24_34);

    unity_WorldToObject._11_21_31_41 = float4(w2oRotation._11_21_31, 0.0f);
    unity_WorldToObject._12_22_32_42 = float4(w2oRotation._12_22_32, 0.0f);
    unity_WorldToObject._13_23_33_43 = float4(w2oRotation._13_23_33, 0.0f);
    unity_WorldToObject._14_24_34_44 = float4(w2oPosition, 1.0f);

#endif


    }

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
       UNITY_DEFINE_INSTANCED_PROP(fixed4, _Color)
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)
    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        fixed4 c = {0,0,255,0};//tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
        #ifdef UNITY_PROCEDURAL_INSTANCING_ENABLED
            c=colorBuffer[unity_InstanceID];
        #endif
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

Maybe something wrong with the matrix calculations?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

WebGL uses right hand rule orientation, and you may be porting code from a left hand rule system (like Unity3D). You can swap this by adjusting the line where you set the translation - swap the assignments for X and Z and see if the rest falls in line.

Comment: Already tried that..